# iOS: Get the voice identifier in spoken content programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, identifier, voice, avspeechsynthesizer

Is it possible to get the current voice identifier programmatically?

We know we can set the voice in iOS Setting -> Accessibility -> Spoken Content -> Voices -> Your Country -> someone's voice, people can download the voices they want in this page.

And I can get all speech voices using below methods:

```
NSArray *allVoices = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices];
for (AVSpeechSynthesisVoice *voice in allVoices) {
    NSLog(@"Voice Language: %@, Identifier: %@, Quality: %ld", voice.language, voice.identifier, (long)voice.quality);
}
```

But I can not know which one is being used currently, the [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice currentLanguageCode] only shows the code like "en-US", but I want to know the current voice identifier like "com.apple.ttsbundle.siri_Marie_fr-FR_compact", is there a way to get it?